# Appended SVG not displayed if created with d3.create()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have implemented tooltips on my d3 chart in observablehq.com: https://observablehq.com/d/27ad6d751cb492de

Then I wanted to take all this code to my project, the problem is that I cannot use this syntax outside observablehq.com:

```
this.node = svg`<g pointer-events="none" display="none"><rect x="${tooltipParams.x}" width="${tooltipParams.width}" y="${tooltipParams.y}" height="${tooltipParams.height}" fill="${tooltipParams.fill}"></rect></g>`
```

So I have rewrited it in alternative way:

```
const _g = d3.create("g").attr('pointer-events', 'none').attr('display', 'none')

_g.append('rect')
.attr('x', tooltipParams.x)
.attr('y', tooltipParams.y)
.attr('height', tooltipParams.height)
.attr('width', tooltipParams.width)
.attr('fill', tooltipParams.fill)

this.node = _g.node()
```

But it does not work. You can make sure by commenting out the line "this.node = _g.node()" in my example. Even the elements in DOM tree are the same in both cases - but it is not displayed if I use d3.create() and so on. And, moreover, if I remove it manually (with dev tools), and right after that add the same svg element into the same place in the parent svg - the tooltip appears (but, for sure, it does not follow the cursor - because it is another new element).

Answer (score 0):

ok, this was because of namespace, need to use d3.create("**svg**:g"), otherwise it creates some element 'g' with namespace undefined, and does not work.